# Remove bullets from Select2 Dropdown Options in Woocommerce

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I've searched around for a good while now trying to find a solution for this issue, but haven't seen anyone else experiencing it so far.

I have a WooCommerce store I'm working on developing, and recently noticed that the select field for the billing state is displaying list-style type bullets in front of the options when expanded.

I've messed around in the CSS including removing any background image and making sure there was no list-style attribute applied to the options, but I'm stuck on as to what's happening here.

The issue can be viewed live at this link: http://grahams.staging.wpengine.com/donate/

Does anyone have any ideas on what could be causing this? My guess is it's somewhere in the woocommerce files but I'm unsure as to where I would start looking.

List of Woo Extensions:

- One Page Checkout
- Name Your Price
- WooCommerce Subscriptions
- WooCommerce Variation
- Swatches and Photos

Other than the above, no customizations have been made. Theme being used is Hybrid.

EDIT: adding an image for those who can't load it/are looking after it's been resolved.

[image]

Comment: Hi Cory, adding a screenshot would be helpful!

Comment: @ViktorMalyi I've added a tinypic link that has a screenshot of the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Please include enough code to reproduce the problem **in the question itself** . Providing a link to your site as the only reference to your code is a problem as you may be providing a moving target as you try to fix it. It also renders your question meaningless for future visitors once the problem is fixed.

Comment: @JonP Thanks for the info, will be sure to do that in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspecting your CSS, there is a background image being applied to all `ul li` elements. See `_elements.scss`, line 96.

```
ul li { background: url(images/build/bullet.png) no-repeat 0 6px; }
```

Adding the following style fixes the issue.

```
.select2-results__option { background-image: none; }
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I looked through the css myself and did not see that rule, not sure how I missed it. Appreciate the second set of eyes.

Comment: If you don't already use them, most browsers have developer tools built in. [Google Chrome Inspector](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) for example is a great way to see exactly what styles are being applied to a given element. This allowed me to immediately see where the bullet points were coming from.